# Can I use my Windows 7 license key when doing a clean Windows 10 USB installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

I've now clicked the "Get windows 10" button on the taskbar of my Windows 7 Home Premium installation, and gotten the email confirming I'm eligible for a free Windows 10 upgrade. [The instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10?OCID=WIP_r_Win10_Body_AddPC) says I'll need the License Key if I'm doing a "first time installation":

> If you will be installing the operating system for the first time, you will need your Windows product key (xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx). For more information about product keys and when they are required, visit the FAQ page.

Even though I proceeded to read the FAQ, it's not perfectly clear to me if the product key on a sticker of my old Windows 7 box can be used on a clean Windows 10 installation, or if I'll receive a new license key some time during the installation. Anyone know this?

Comment: As far as i know the old license keys won't work on the 10 install. I read about, that if you upgraded your windows through windows update the 10 will become already activated then you will have a key to the 10 but until that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted to install Win 10 using a Win 7 Home Premium key I knew to be good - wouldn't work.

What did work was installing Win 7, activating it, and then running the Win 10 installation on it.  The installer won't ask for a key at all.

Good luck!

Comment: Did you run the Win 10 installation as upgrade or as clean installation on the Windows 7 one?

Comment: "Clean" installation on top of supported OS (7,8) will work. Although you'll still end up with the old Windows folder backed up in case you want to rollback (automatically removed after 30 days)